# Autenticação do Laravel 10 não esta funcionando quando a rota não está protegida!

Tags: laravel

O laravel 10 tem uma classe Auth que pode verificar se o usuario está autenticado.

Mas eu venho notando que, quando uma rota não está protegida pelo middleware de autenticação, Auth::check() retorna falso, mesmo se no header da requisição, o Bearer token está sendo enviado.
E quando a rota está protegida pelo middleware de autenticação, ai sim o Auth::check() funciona.

Alguem poderia me explicar o por quê isso acontece, ou se existe alguma forma para reverter essa situação? Poder ter acesso ao possível user autenticado mesmo quando a rota não esta autenticada.
Alguém tem alguma dica, algum artigo que poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score -3):

O sanctum que verifica o bearer token para autenticar o usuário logado. Se a rota estiver fora do middleware auth:sanctum não vai funcionar mesmo. Documentação aqui -> [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#protecting-routes)

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    // Sua rota aqui dentro
});
```